# Tikz mindmaps overriding level distance and sibling angle for a specific node

Tags: tikz, mindmap

Is there any way of overriding the defined level distance and sibling angle for a specific node? So for example if I have the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every node/.style=concept, concept color=black, text=white,
  level 1/.append style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=60},
  level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45},
  level 3/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=30}]

  \node {RootNode}
    child { node {NodeA}
      child { node {NodeA1}}
      child { node {NodeA2}}
      child { node {NodeA3}}
    }
    child { node {NodeB}
      child { node {NodeB1}}
      child { node {NodeB2}}
    }
    child { node {NodeC}
      [clockwise from=90]
      child { node {NodeC1}}
      child { node {NodeC2}}
      child { node {NodeC3}}
      child { node {NodeC4}}
      child { node {NodeC5}}
    }
    child {node {NodeD}
      child {node {NodeD1}}
      child {node {NodeD2}}
    }
    child { node {NodeE}
      child {node {NodeE1}}
      child {node {NodeE2}}
    }
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Is it possible to push NodeC further out from the RootNode (longer level distance) and decrease the sibling angle for just NodeC. I know I can use grow to position the sibling nodes manually.

Thanks

Comment: By decreasing the sibling angle for NodeC, do you mean you want Node C1-5 to be closer from one another?

Comment: Yes. Thank you you solution below is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the attributes of that specific node:

```
...
child[level distance=6cm,level 2/.append style={sibling angle=35}] { node {NodeC}
...
```

[image]